# How to refresh total sidebar when change qty by ajax in cart page

Tags: magento2, cart

I am changing the qty of items using ajax, when ajax is successful then i want to refresh my sidebar total.

Minicart updates automatically because of sections but the total does not update.

How can i do this?

Comment: no solution to this question?

Answer (score 2):

I was doing the same, updating the item quantities in the Shopping Cart page using ajax, after my ajax call I do this:

```
storage.get(resourceUrlManager.getUrlForCartTotals(quote), false)
       .done(
           function (response) {
               quote.setTotals(response);
           })
       .fail(
           function (response) {
               //do your error handling
       });
```

In my JS file I imported these to make it works:

`'Magento_Checkout/js/model/resource-url-manager'`,`'mage/storage'` and `'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote'`

Also, `storage` can be replaced by an ajax request, with the next format:

```
$.ajax({
        url: resourceUrlManager.getUrlForCartTotals(quote),
        type: 'GET',
        global: false,
        contentType: 'application/json'
        });
```

but I wanted to keep the Magento style.